# Pyarmor - Marshal loads failed

Tags: pyarmor

How do I fix the issue "The python version in runtime is different from the build time".

When I try to run the obfuscated file present in a folder I am getting this error.

Please help me with this!!

Answer (score 2):

According to this:

https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/questions.html

You are probably running Pyarmor (building your obfuscated code) with a different version than the environment where the app is running. Find out the version that runs the app and try to run Pyarmor with the same version, for example by creating an environment with that version.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was using WSL to execute my program. Not using WSL and running it with windows solved it for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).